# Angular module not loading

Tags: angularjs

So I am creating a new module with a single controller, saved in controllers directory off of the app directory:

```
var tables = angular.module('tables',[]).controller('setName', function ($scope) {
  $scope.userName = userName;
  $scope.userPassword = userPassword;
});
```

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ang</title>

</head>
<script src="/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="tables">
  <div ng-controller="setName">
    User Name: <input type="text" ng-model="userName" ><br>
    Password: <input type="text" ng-model="userPassword" ><br><br>

    User Name: {{userName}}<br>
    Password: {{userPassword}}<br>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using express to serve the page:

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');
//Load tables
//var tables = angular.module('table');
// Create express app
var app = express();
//Load http express wrapper
var http= require('http');
//Create variable for the port the server listens on
var srvPort = 3000;
//Make a static path to node_modules  directory
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));

app.use(express.static('controllers'));
//Make a static path to the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


var server = http.createServer(app).listen(srvPort, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + srvPort);
});

require('./public/javascript/sockets.js').initialize(server);
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module tables due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?  p0=tables
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:25:136
at b (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:24:188)
at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:24:431
at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:39:287
at n (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
at g (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:39:135)
at fb (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:43:164)
at Ac.c (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:20:449
```

So my question is, why is my module not loading?

Any help would be appreciated!

Z

Comment: have you tried using `tables.controller(...)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not loading it in `<head>`. You have only `socket.io.js` and `angular.min.js` but not the JS file containing your module.

Comment: It is often the simple things that get you! Thanks Martin for the help!